# Change default strategy for Chewy on application initialisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, chewy-gem

I have a requirement in my application to use the `urgent` strategy. The Chewy document has a way to override the strategy in the application but every time a Chewy call is made, it has to be wrapped up in a code block. I am wondering if there is a simpler way to just override the strategy on initialisation.

I referred the Chewy documentation and have tried this but it is valid for only this particular call.

```
Chewy.strategy(:urgent) do
  City.popular.map(&:do_some_update_action!)
end
```